# How to invoke the values from setenv.sh file to server.xml file in tomcat? its working for context.xml but its not working for server.xml

Tags: linux, xml, tomcat, tomcat9

How to invoke the values from setenv.sh file to server.xml file in tomcat? its working for context.xml but its not working for server.xml

I am passing the values from setenv.sh file for the variable in server.xml file.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question. Since variable substitution has been improved during the Tomcat 9.0 release series, what version of Tomcat (exactly) are you using?

Comment: tomcat 9 I am using and the variable KeyPass="*****" in setenv.sh file and i have the variable keystore password = "$KeyPass" in server.xml file.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69346935/edit) your question and add the interesting parts of `setenv.sh`, `server.xml` and `context.xml`. From what you write variable substitution should not work neither in `server.xml` nor in `context.xml`.